# How to pass swig generated SWIGTYPE_p_type as parameter in Java

Tags: java, c, swig

I have an `enum` in C:

type.h

```
typedef enum{one, two, three=0x0}numbers;
work(numbers* param);
```

generate.i

```
%module swig
%{
#include "type.h"
%}
%include "type.h"
```

swig generates wierd `SWIGTYPE_p_numbers` class. How to use it? How to pass it as parameter in function?

EDIT:

swig.java

```
public class swig {
  public static void work(SWIGTYPE_p_numbers param){
    swigJNI.work(SWIGTYPE_p_numbers.getCPtr(param));
  }
}
```

SWIGTYPE_p_numbers.java

```
public class SWIGTYPE_p_numbers {
  private long swigCPtr;

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_numbers (long cPtr, boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_numbers () {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_numbers obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}
```

Comment: java or c? you mentioned java but the code is c..

Comment: I added  java classes generated by swig

Comment: some one else is talking about same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856490/how-to-pass-a-value-to-a-function-when-the-value-is-swigtype

Comment: may be this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005123/how-do-i-convert-to-type-swigtype-p-void-in-swig-generated-java-bindings